# How can I view web page content that is generated using angular JS?

Tags: python

I have an app that uses [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to analyze and act on web page text. But it does not seem to work on this page that is likely built with angular: https://bio.tools/bowtie, in that the source HTML is different than the actual content. I am trying to collect the DOI that is referenced on the page (10.1186/gb-2009-10-3-r25), but when requests picks up the HTML source the DOI is not there.

I've heard that Google is able to parse pages that are generated using javascript. How do they do it? Any tips on viewing the DOI information with python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need an engine which runs the javascript of the http response for you (like an internet browser does). You can use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io) for this and then parsing the html it returns with [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://bio.tools/bowtie"
path = "path/to/chrome/webdriver"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(path) # Can also be Firefox, etc.
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
...
```